# use aggregation in Where and order

Tags: sql-server

I have a users and an activities table.

Users have activities with points

users
id, name

user_activities,
id, user_id, points

Now I want to get a list of the user with the highest points below 100:

```
select top 1[name], SUM(user_activities.points) as userpoints 
    from [users] inner join [user_activities] on [users].[id] = [user_activities].[user_id]  
    WHERE [userpoints] < 100 
    group by [name]
    order by [userpoints] desc
```

Unfortunately I get an error message: Unknown column userpoints

Comment: To filter aggregate data you need to use HAVING. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql

Comment: Having SUM(user_activities.points) < 100

Answer (score 1):

Filtering aggregates is done by HAVING:

```
select top 1[name], 
SUM(user_activities.points) as userpoints 

from [users] 

inner join [user_activities] 
    on [users].[id] = [user_activities].[user_id]  
group by [name]
HAVING SUM(user_activities.points) < 100 
order by SUM(user_activities.points) desc
```